# ArrayBuffer when stringified becomes empty object

Tags: javascript, json, stringify, arraybuffer

In my app, i'm uploading a file using FileReader and parsing it as an `ArrayBuffer`. The file properties are saved in an object, with structure like this:

```
file: {
    name: 'fileName', // type string
    content: ArrayBuffer // read like  FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(uploadedFile)
}
```

When I want to save the file to backend, I'm using axios, and sending a request like this:

```
axios({
    url: "/api/v3/synchronous/commands",
    method: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(file),
    headers,
})
```

The problem is that when it get's stringifed, `content` inside file becomes an empty object `{}`. How to go about this issue, without having to convert `ArrayBuffer` to something else, and then converting it back to `ArrayBuffer`?

Comment: You can't really. "*The `ArrayBuffer` doesn't work, how can I fix it without changing the `ArrayBuffer`?*" :-P

Comment: I'd suggest [constructing an actual `File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File)

Comment: That's not an option for now. Currently, it has to be done like this, because there are some more custom manipulations, not related to this, that I have to do. I tried this method, but it doesn't seem to work: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String

Comment: If you are open to conversions, the simplest would be `JSON.stringify(Array.from(new Uint32Array(buffer)))`

Comment: I'm open to conversions if I can't avoid them, and it seems I can't. I'm not sure I quote understand what does this piece of code do - does it convert from string to arraybuffer or the other way around?

Comment: It converts from a buffer to an array, so that you can JSON.stringify it. The reverse process, after `JSON.parse`ing it, would be `Uint32Array.from(array).buffer`